# Can I return to previous commit in a single submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I would like to have my application set up into some services, but all in one repository. So I wanted to add one submodule for each service (I am only having two for the moment). So my project hierarchy is:

```
- root
|--rootDoc.txt
|--.git
|
|---- sub1
    |--sub1.txt
    |--.git
|---- sub2
    |--sub2.txt
    |--.git
```

Now I made the following changes:

- change `sub1.txt`
- commit `sub1` submodule
- push main to master
- change `sub2.txt`
- commit `sub2` submodule
- push main to master

Now I'd like to return `sub1`-submodule to the state before the last changes in it but keep `sub2` in its current state. If that is not possible for submodules, is there another solution for my problem or would I need to use two completely  different repositories?

**Edit:**
What I tried:

```
c:\dev\root\sub1>git log
commit a172db9a5f11738383d28e082db2c22d3f2d3e75 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: %me%
Date:   Sun Dec 2 20:24:59 2018 +0100

    updated sub2

commit 0becb718a4db9c73b03fa65e332f20c7715463cb
Author: %me%
Date:   Sun Dec 2 20:23:40 2018 +0100

    sub1 actual now

commit 85d68703bff1af2b95a7ee8d7926d7fd700b1da4
Author: %me%
Date:   Sun Dec 2 20:10:50 2018 +0100

    Added submodules

commit b3b67de3e54f1db7e56d516af2baaf50541f7ca2
Author: %me%
Date:   Sun Dec 2 20:05:44 2018 +0100

    initial commit

c:\dev\root\sub1>git checkout 85d68703bff1af2b95a7ee8d7926d7fd700b1da4
Note: checking out '85d68703bff1af2b95a7ee8d7926d7fd700b1da4'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 85d6870 Added submodules
```

After this checkout my `sub2` is also changed although I checked out from the `sub1`-dir (where the other submodule is located).

Comment: From your tree, it seems like you have 3 repositories already - one per folder. If you revert just the sub1 repo, sub2 shouldn't be affected, but the root repo will see that as a modification.

Comment: @SergioS. That was what I expected, but sadly when I went `git log` from my `sub1`-dir I got the log of the root repo. And when I went back also `sub2` went back to the state it head early on. Do I need the submodules to have "standalone"-repos only for the project? I do not have a repo for `sub1` or a repo for `sub2`, all I added was a bitbucket repository for the `root`-git        I updated my post and tried to describe my problem a little more in detail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do what's in your title question ("return to previous commit in a single submodule").  Every submodule is an independent repository in its own right.  What's not clear is what you actually done.  I suspect that you have made *one* repository with several sub-directories, and perhaps another two repositories that live under the one repository but *are not submodules*.

---

It's worth stepping back here and defining some terms.  I'm not really thrilled with Git's terminology here ("submodule" and "superproject" are kind of clumsy) but I will stick with them.

- A *submodule* is a Git repository.
- A *superproject* is a Git repository.

Obviously this is not much help,  so let's add some qualifiers:

- A *submodule* is a Git repository that is currently being used by another Git repository which we call the *superproject*.  There is exactly one superproject for this submodule Git repo.
- A *superproject* is a Git repository that is currently using another Git repository as a submodule.  There may be multiple submodules within this superproject.

(This leads to the possibility that some Git repository is simultaneously a submodule *and* a superproject.  This is a bit of a nightmare and you should try to avoid it, but it does happen.)

Now, when a superproject makes demands on another Git repository that the superproject is using as a submodule, the *way* the superproject Git does this is—at least normally—to command the submodule Git to enter *detached HEAD* mode.  *Any* Git repository can be in this state, but most normal repositories aren't, except when you're in the middle of a long rebase, or are using `git checkout commit-or-tag` to move to a specific historic commit.  Normally, when developing, you're on a branch like `master` or `develop`, which is the opposite of "detached HEAD": here the name `HEAD` is figuratively attached to the branch name.  So `git checkout master` attaches your `HEAD` to `master`, and `git checkout develop` attaches your `HEAD` to develop.

(`HEAD`, written in all-capitals like this, always—*always*—refers to the current commit in the current Git repository.  The underlying implementation of this is that the `.git` directory that holds the repository has a file named `HEAD` in it. This `.git/HEAD` file either contains a *branch name*, in which case you're on that branch, or it contains a *commit hash ID*, in which case you have a detached HEAD at that commit.  Since Git stores this in a file, it's possible on Windows and MacOS to use `head` in all lower-case, but it's better to stick with the all-capitals version.  If you want a shortcut that's easier to type, `@` by itself also means `HEAD`.)

When you want to use a regular repository, in a system in which you start by cloning the repository (rather than creating it from scratch), you do this:

```
git clone <url> [<directory>]
```

e.g., `git clone https://github.com/git/git.git` to clone the Git repository for Git via GitHub.  This creates a `git` directory wherever you are right now.  If for some reason you wanted the clone to be put in `/tmp/git` you would use `git clone https://github.com/git/git.git /tmp/git`.  So there are two key items that Git needs, in order to make a clone:

- a URL, and
- a path where the clone should go.

The URL is typically an `https://` or `ssh://` style URL, listing some upstream host / server (or cloud-system such as GitHub) and a path on that host / server.  (Note that `git@github.com:path/to/repo.git` is just shorthand for `ssh://git@github.com/path/to/repo.git`.  The two mean exactly the same thing.)

The process of adding a submodule to an existing repository is much the same:

```
git submodule add <url> [<directory>]
```

The *`url`* here will *also* typically begin with `https://` or `ssh://`.  The `<directory>` is the path *within* your repository, i.e., the place to put the submodule.

The reason for this URL-and-path is that `git submodule add` will in fact run `git clone` for you.  The clone it makes will be an ordinary Git repository, because a submodule *is* an ordinary Git repository.  Git just needs to know *where do I get the clone from* and *where should I put it within this repository*.

The other thing that `git submodule add` will do—the extra part that makes your *current* Git repository act as a *superproject* to that submodule—is to create or update a file named `.gitmodules`, and to add an entry to your superproject's index.

Note that the subproject does not have to know about its superproject, and in the bad old days, *really* didn't know anything about it.  (In modern Git the subproject's `.git` directory gets migrated into the superproject's `.git` directory.  The `.git` that would be found at the submodule is replaced with a *file* that points the submodule to its superproject's holding area.)

Anyway, the side effect of all of this is that the *set of commits in a submodule* is determined by the contents of the submodule alone.  The superproject has no effect on it!  The submodule is just a clone of some existing URL.

This is not the way you're trying to use submodules, but before we get to that, let's look at the rest of the normal operation of all of this.  We have some superproject—a local Git repository that is perhaps a clone of some `origin` repository—where we make our superproject commits.  Within this superproject, we have now created a file named `.gitmodules` that gives the URL and path of *another* Git repository.  Let's say the path is `dir/sub`.  If we run:

```
cd dir/sub
```

we find that we are now in the work-tree of a *separate* clone, that has *its own* `origin/master` and `master` and so on; but this clone has a detached HEAD.  Running `git log` shows the the detached-HEAD commit, then its parent(s) and their parent(s) and so on, as if history ends at whatever commit we have out as the detached HEAD.  This is our submodule Git repository.

If we `cd` back up into the original repository:

```
cd -    # or cd ../..
```

we're back into the main repository.  Using the ordinary file system tools shows us that `dir/sub` exists now and is a directory.  There is a file (or if your Git is older, a diretory) named `dir/sub/.git`.  If it's a file, it contains one line reading:

```
gitdir: ../../.git/modules/sub
```

Running `git status` shows two added files:

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   .gitmodules
        new file:   dir/sub
```

But inspecting the *index*—which is a little tricky; I'll use `git ls-files` here—shows that `dir/sub` is not a *directory* at all:

```
$ git ls-files --stage dir/sub
160000 50298bbf97b317f17b3e1cf9287e912fb5de886e 0       dir/sub
```

Entries with mode `160000` are what Git calls a *gitlink*.

If you know that `dir/sub` is a gitlink, you can view its hash ID more directly using `git rev-parse`.  The syntax `:0:dir/sub` means "dir/sub from the index (at slot zero)":

```
$ git rev-parse :0:dir/sub
50298bbf97b317f17b3e1cf9287e912fb5de886e
```

These tell us the same thing, except that if `dir/sub` *weren't* a submodule, we would be able to see that in the `git ls-files --stage` output.

#### This is how Git generally envisions submodule usage

The general idea here is that, in your superproject, you use some sort of third-party library (say, Google gRPC) that you personally don't control in any way.  Instead, you write your software and make it work with *one particular version* of that library:

```
$ (cd dir/sub; git checkout v3.2.1)
```

By checking out some particular tag in the submodule, you *move* the detached HEAD to that particular commit.  Then you make any changes needed to your own project—your superproject—to make it work *with* v3.2.1 or whatever version that is:

```
$ ... make some changes ...
$ git add ... files ...
```

Having now updated *your* files, you now also update the *gitlink* entry that says that your superproject Git should `git checkout` the one particular commit that *you* have right now in *your* submodule:

```
$ git add dir/sub     # update the gitlink to whatever hash v3.2.1 represents
```

Now when you make a *new* commit, the superproject commit continues to list the other repository—with its URL, whatever that is, and its path, `dir/sub`—in your `.gitmodules`, *and* this same commit declares: *This commit works with the submodule detached to <gitlink submodule hash>.*

So, whenever someone runs `git clone` on your superproject, and then does a `git checkout` of *that particular superproject commit*, a subsequent:

```
$ git submodule update
```

will make sure that `dir/sub` has *that particular gitlink-ed commit* checked out, as the detached HEAD.  Now your superproject and submodule are in sync, and you can build.

#### This is not the way you're trying to use submodules

In your case, you *already have the submodule Git repositories*.  They may or may not have a suitable upstream repository.  They exist at `sub1` and `sub2`.  I'll use, as my example, `dir/sub` again, though:

```
$ git submodule add ./dir/sub dir/sub
Adding existing repo at 'dir/sub' to the index
```

The URL here, `./dir/sub`, is pretty useless to anyone else.  (It has to start with `./` or `../` to be relative to the current working directory—Git refuses to add the submodule without the leading `./`.)

At this point, the same thing happens as with a normal URL: Git has created or updated your `.gitmodules` to list the URL and path:

```
$ cat .gitmodules
[submodule "dir/sub"]
        path = dir/sub
        url = ./dir/sub
```

and put the hash ID that corresponds to the submodule's `HEAD` into the index to serve as the next committed gitlink entry:

```
$ (cd dir/sub; git rev-parse HEAD)
1fdcf14961c81d03496b359389058410f0169782
$ git rev-parse :0:dir/sub
1fdcf14961c81d03496b359389058410f0169782
$ git status --short
A  .gitmodules
A  dir/sub
```

Thus, if you now make a new commit at this point, the new commit will have the `.gitmodules` and index entries needed to make this Git repository attempt to manage—or clone, if it's missing—the other Git repository into `dir/sub`, based on the URL `./dir/sub`.

This URL is of course entirely useless unless there's *already* a Git repository at `dir/sub`, but that's how we tell this Git that it is being the superproject to another Git repository at `dir/sub`.  You *can* use Git this way, and as long as you *already have* another Git repository at `dir/sub`, your superproject Git will be OK with that and will command it.  The command your superproject Git will issue to the submodule Git is: *Check out this one specific commit, as a detached HEAD.*

#### How the superproject sees submodule changes

Assume you go into the submodule and use `git checkout` to check out, or even create, some *other* commit, perhaps by doing `git checkout` of some branch name and then maybe working in the repository as usual and committing.  Then you `cd` back to the superproject and run `git status`.  Your Git will tell you that the submodule is modified (note the blank *before* the `M` here):

```
$ git status --short
 M dir/sub
```

This modification exists, but is not yet in your *index*, i.e., is not yet set up to be committed:

```
$ (cd dir/sub; git rev-parse HEAD)
860be47095f79afbf94c62d0c3936a9875905e16
$ git rev-parse :0:dir/sub
1fdcf14961c81d03496b359389058410f0169782
```

As you can see, the submodule *is* detached at `860be47095f79afbf94c62d0c3936a9875905e16`, even though the index says that the next commit will contain a directive to use `1fdcf14961c81d03496b359389058410f0169782`.  **This is exactly like any modified file in the same repository,* except that you use `git add` here to tell Git: *put the new hash ID in* rather than telling it *copy the work-tree contents in*.

Hence, once we do `git add`, the `--short` status output will move the `M` one letter to the left:

```
$ git add dir/sub
$ git status --short
M  dir/sub
```

because now the superproject's index entry for the submodule differs from the `HEAD` value for that submodule, but does match the actual submodule as found in the work-tree.  So now, if everything is ready and we want to tell our superproject Git to command the submodule Git to use `860be47095f79afbf94c62d0c3936a9875905e16` in the next commit we make, we're ready to make that commit now:

```
$ git commit
[edit a message, etc]
```

Again, the keys here are:

- Each submodule is its own Git repository.
- The superproject finds each submodule by path and/or and by `.gitmodules`, as needed.  A new clone of *just* the superproject obviously does not have any of the submodules cloned yet, so that's what the `.gitmodules` entries are good for: they provide the URL and the path!
- The superproject Git can look at each submodule and find its `HEAD`: that gets the superproject Git the actual hash ID, and lets you `git add` that hash ID to the superproject's index, ready for the *next* commit you make in the superproject.
- Or, the superproject Git can command the submodule Git to `git checkout`, as a detached HEAD, the one specific commit hash ID that is in the *superproject*'s index right now.

If you want to make your superproject command multiple submodules, you `git submodule add` all those submodules.  To make sure those submodules get the right commit hash ID checked-out as detached HEADs, you *enter* the submodules, *put* them on the right commits, and then `git add` the submodules in the superproject.

In modern Git, the `git submodule` command has some fairly-fancy tricks to coordinate updating submodules using branch names found in the *remote* (`origin`, usually) for the submodule.  The idea here is that if you *are* using, say, Google gRPC, and you want to upgrade, `git submodule` can replace several of the above steps—`cd`-ing into the submodule, running `git fetch`, running `git checkout`, and `cd`-ing back—with one step.  But the actual design of submodules is still "detached HEAD as commanded by superproject": it's up to you to make sure that the superproject Git repository records the correct submodule hash IDs.